# .NET Core - Get project description in C# code

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm current working on a .NET Core project.

Here is part of my `csproj` file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <Description>This is the project description.</Description>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="SomeProject.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

As you can see, there is a `Description` string in the `PropertyGroup` values:

> This is the project description

I need to get this value at runtime in C# code. Like:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string projectDescription = ??? // How can I get: "This is the project description"
    Console.WriteLine(projectDescription );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access version and more general properties of your project using:

```
GetCustomAttribute<T>()
```

For other values for T, see the attributes listed on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection?view=netcore-2.0

Example:

```cs
using System.Reflection;

var description = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyDescriptionAttribute>().Description;
```

Comment: var description = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyDescriptionAttribute>().Description;
Solved my problem. Thank you so much!